# How can I customize Pandoc convertions?

Tags: pandoc

I am a developer and just found pandoc. Looks really cool.

I have alot of my school work done in latex and as a developer i would like to extend the latex to html to my needs.

I just need a few pointers on where to start.

The first task I want to solve is that when it reads a \maketitle i want to generate a html title block.

Next step, i want it to beable to read \def \CodeName {\textbf{OpenCMS}} and whenever i have used \CodeName{} in latex it will use the stuff from the variable.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-s` option, pandoc should give you an HTML title block based on the title information in the LaTeX file.

On the other issue:  Try using `\newcommand` instead of `\def`.  Recent versions of pandoc understand `\newcommand` macro definitions.

Comment: Cool. I guess that will do for now then. I must likely will come back asking for more when i run into other issues :) Thanks for answering.